# Drive not mounting in Ubuntu MATE

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, data-recovery

I have 2 drives: 1 SSD and 1 hard disk drive. I installed Windows on the SSD so I could upgrade the BIOS on my motherboard, this was successful.

I then went and downloaded the latest version of Ubuntu MATE and now that I am up and running, the hard disk drive is not showing up or mounting. It shows as “unallocated space.”

I did not format this drive at all, but somehow I think Windows got to it. If I can get the data off of here, I don't care about formatting it. I just need the data. Screenshots below.

Is there some type of program I can use to see the data when the partition is not readable?

```
lsblk -f

NAME   FSTYPE   LABEL           UUID                                 FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINT
loop0  squashfs                                                            0   100% /snap/core18/1705
loop1  squashfs                                                            0   100% /snap/snapd/7264
loop2  squashfs                                                            0   100% /snap/software-boutique/54
loop3  squashfs                                                            0   100% /snap/ubuntu-mate-welcome/524
loop4  squashfs                                                            0   100% /snap/snapd/8542
loop5  squashfs                                                            0   100% /snap/core18/1885
loop6  squashfs                                                            0   100% /snap/ubuntu-mate-welcome/539
sda                                                                                 
\u251c\u2500sda1 vfat                     FFB2-A30C                               511M     0% /boot/efi
\u251c\u2500sda2                                                                              
\u2514\u2500sda5 ext4                     625fab32-100d-4169-b259-2dc8cf37542e   95.2G     8% /
sdb    ext4     3TB             4cc364f9-f1f1-48f1-89d3-d2663e406a31                
\u2514\u2500sdb1 ntfs     System Reserved 9CBEA905BEA8D8D2
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: [Testdisk](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) is your friend.  See [this](https://forum.cgsecurity.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?t=6436) post.  Windows probably changed the partition table to GPT from MBR when you did this.  Next time, disconnect the other drive when you let the windows installer play.. I guess you already know that now.. :P

Comment: Will Testdisk let me change the partition table back to GPT? Edit: Testdisk guesses the partition type is "None".

Comment: I am not sure.  If you REALLY CARE about the data on this drive, use the linux `dd` utility to copy it to another drive and play with only the copy.  Then you can be stupid over and over without losing your data.  Also `lde` should let you see if there is still data on the drive you care about.  I know this is a total PITA.. but sometimes ya have to.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have extra drives to dd a copy to in such a great size (3TB).